# How to add a template to a Kendo grid toolbar

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am trying to add a custom template to a Kendo MVC grid.

My template should contain 2 things:

1. Create button to add new record to the grid
2. Autocomplete box to filter the data in the grid.

I am trying the following code:

```
.ToolBar(toolbar =>
{
    toolbar.Template(
        @<text>
            <div class="toolbar">
                <label class="category-label" for="category">Filter by name:</label>
                @(Html.Kendo().AutoComplete()
                    .Name("employees")
                    .DataTextField("empName")
                    .Filter("contains")
                    .MinLength(3)
                    .Events(e => e.Change("nameChange"))
                    .DataSource(ds =>
                    {
                        ds.Read("FilteringList", "Employee");
                    })
                )
            </div>
        </text>);
    toolbar.Create().Text("New Record");
})
```

but this is not working. I can only see the autocomplete box.

Any ideas on how I can accomplish my requirements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the below line

```
toolbar.Create().Text("New Record");
```

from the ToolBar Section and add the button inside the template.
Please see below code:

```
.ToolBar(toolbar =>
{
    toolbar.Template(
        @<text>
            <div class="toolbar">
                <a class="k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-add" 
                   href="/YourControllerName/YouCreateActionResultJsonName?grdSearch-mode=insert">
                    New Record
                </a>
                <label class="category-label" for="category">Filter by name:</label>
                @(Html.Kendo().AutoComplete()
                    .Name("employees")
                    .DataTextField("empName")
                    .Filter("contains")
                    .MinLength(3)
                    .Events(e => e.Change("nameChange"))
                    .DataSource(ds =>
                    {
                        ds.Read("FilteringList", "Employee");
                    })
                )
            </div>
        </text>);
})
```

Answer (score 7):

Nitin Mall's answer can be simplified by replacing

```
<a class="k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-add"   
href="/YourControllerName/YouCreateActionResultJsonName?grdSearch-mode=insert">
New Record</a>
```

with

```
<a class='k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-add' 
href='#'><span class='k-icon k-add'></span>Add new record</a>
```

This works because the grid uses jquery delegate to attach the grid's click event handler which calls the AddRow method to the item with class "k-grid-add"

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach I used in my code (after I give up on template)

1. Create it separately

- Dropdown I want in the toolbar wrapped in div with "d-none" class (to prevent flickering)

  ```
       <div id="elementIMove" class="d-none">
           @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
               .Name("SelectRevision")
               .DataTextField("Text")
               .DataValueField("Value")
               .BindTo((System.String)ViewData["SelectedRevision"])
               .Events(e => e.Change("onRevisionChange"))
               .DataSource(dataSource =>
               {
                   dataSource.Read(read => read.Action("Method", "Controller", new { opportunityId = Model.CurrentOpportunityId, }))
                   .ServerFiltering(false);
               })
           )
       </div>
  ```
- Grid

  ```
   @(Html.Kendo().Grid<SuperDuperGrid>()
       .Name("MySuperDuperGrid")
       .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "grid-super-duper" })
       .Columns(columns =>
       {...                        
       .ToolBar(toolbar =>
       {
          toolbar.Create().Text("Add");
          toolbar.Search();
          toolbar.Custom().Text(" Export").Name("export");
          toolbar.Custom().Text(" Import").Name("import");
    })...)
  ```

2. Do script "on ready"

   ```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#elementIMove').prependTo($('#MySuperDuperGrid> .k-toolbar.k-grid-toolbar'));
        $('#elementIMove').removeClass('d-none');
    })
   ```
3. Done. Maybe little ugly, but Kendo can be an enemy.