# Multiple overloads for Kendo grid Toolbar?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm trying to configure a Kendo grid toolbar to have the Kendo "Create" function within the grid, as well also have custom buttons located within. Here is what I have so far:

```
   @(Html.Kendo().Grid<VIEWMODELHERE>()
            .Name("UserProfileGrid")
            .Resizable(c => c.Columns(true))
            .Selectable()
            .Filterable()
            .Groupable()
            .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp).TemplateName("UserCreateTemplate"))

            .ToolBar(x => x.Create(), x.Template(@<text>

                    @(Html.Kendo().Button()
                    .Name("ButtonAddUser")
                    .HtmlAttributes(new { type = "k-button" })
                    .Icon("downloads")
                    .Content("Add User")
                    .Events(e => e.Click("createUser")))

                    @(Html.Kendo().Button()
                    .Name("ButtonEditUser")
                    .HtmlAttributes(new { type = "k-button" })
                    .Icon("settings")
                    .Content("Edit User")
                    .Events(e => e.Click("Edituser")))

                    @(Html.Kendo().Button()
                    .Name("ButtonRefreshPage")
                    .HtmlAttributes(new { type = "k-button" })
                    .Icon("history")
                    .Content("Refresh Page")
                    .Events(e => e.Click("RefreshPage")))

                    @(Html.Kendo().Button()
                    .Name("ButtonDeleteUser")
                    .HtmlAttributes(new { type = "k-button" })
                    .Icon("history")
                    .Content("Delete a user")
                    .Events(e => e.Click("DeleteUser")))

                    @(Html.Kendo().Button()
                    .Name("ButtonAbout")
                    .HtmlAttributes(new { type = "k-button" })
                    .Icon("history")
                    .Content("About")
                    .Events(e => e.Click("aboutButtonClick")))
            </text>)));
```

The problem is that I cannot seem to use the lambda functions to create the button correctly because it does not read the create function correctly.

Comment: What does this not to that you want it to do?

Comment: There is a syntax error where x.Template(@<text>.... it doesnt load any of my buttons. But no matter how I confuddle with it it still will not eat my code.

Comment: May be you can try similar solution mentioned here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24844750/add-template-to-kendo-grid-toolbar

Comment: There isn't a question here.  Your posted code doesn't compile.  My answer below explains how to make it compile.

Comment: I do not believe your code compiles. It was not compiling in mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prashant you are correct! For future users who have this problem, you can do this easily:

```
<a class='k-button k-grid-add' href='#'>Add new User</a>
```

so I now have:

```
  toolbar.Template(@<text>


                    <a class='k-button k-grid-add' href='#'>Add new User</a>

                    @(Html.Kendo().Button()
                    .Name("ButtonEditUser")
                    .HtmlAttributes(new { type = "k-button" })
                    .Icon("settings")
                    .Content("Edit User")
                    .Events(x => x.Click("Edituser")))

                        @(Html.Kendo().Button()
                    .Name("ButtonRefreshPage")
                    .HtmlAttributes(new { type = "k-button" })
                    .Icon("history")
                    .Content("Refresh Page")
                    .Events(x => x.Click("RefreshPage")))

                        @(Html.Kendo().Button()
                    .Name("ButtonDeleteUser")
                    .HtmlAttributes(new { type = "k-button" })
                    .Icon("history")
                    .Content("Delete a user")
                    .Events(x => x.Click("DeleteUser")))

                        @(Html.Kendo().Button()
                    .Name("ButtonAbout")
                    .HtmlAttributes(new { type = "k-button" })
                    .Icon("history")
                    .Content("About")
                    .Events(x => x.Click("aboutButtonClick")))
                    </text>);})
```

Maybe not pretty, the blending of razer and html... but it works for our Agile environment.

Answer (score 6):

As you know, you have a syntax problem.  Since you are using more than one command inside the Toolbar command (x.Create and x.Template), you need to turn that into a block by wrapping the body in the "{}".  After x.Create() goes a ";" to end the line.

```
.ToolBar(x =>
{
    x.Create();
    x.Template(@<text>

        @(Html.Kendo().Button()
    .Name("ButtonAddUser")
    .HtmlAttributes(new { type = "k-button" })
    .Icon("downloads")
    .Content("Add User")
    .Events(e => e.Click("createUser")))
    </text>);
})
```

Comment: that doesn't work actually. The reason being is that x.Create(); actually creates a button a itself that is reference to the model that the grid is created from. I should have been more clear in my question I think.. but thank you for your efforts and time.

Comment: Interesting.  Not sure how I could have possibly had any clue what question you were asking.  You had complaints about getting the syntax to work correctly and I explained how to fix that.